# WiX 3.7 use Microsoft Bootstrapper

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I'm new to WiX. I found tutorials which included Microsoft Bootsrappers directly in a wix setup project. Unfortunately this is not posible with wix3.7 as it expect to use WiX a Bootstrapper Project for checking prerequisites.

How do I use the provided Bootstrappers from Microsoft in my WiX 3.7 Bootstrapper Project?

Answer (score 0):

If you have built a Microsoft Bootstrapper that you want to include in a WiX Bootstrapper project then create an ExePackage element for it under Wix/Bundle/Chain (typically in a file named Bundle.wxs). List every file needed in a Payload element under ExePackage.

The list is easily generated with a Text Template (.tt). Unfortunately, WiX projects (.wixproj) don't provide for adding or building such files. The simple workaround is to create an empty C# project, add a Text Template file there and add just the generated WiX file to your WiX project.

Here is an example Text Template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ output extension=".wxs" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
    <!-- 
    Generated file list for a WixBootstrapper project
    <#=DateTime.Now.ToString("s")#>
-->
<#
// Assumes all projects are in sibling folders so relative paths can be used
  var thisProjectDir = new FileInfo(this.Host.TemplateFile).Directory;
  var appProjectDir = Path.GetFullPath(thisProjectDir + @"\..\DemoApplication");
  var sourceFiles = Directory
      .GetFiles(appProjectDir + @"\publish", "*.*",  SearchOption.AllDirectories)
      .Select(s => s.Replace(appProjectDir, @"..\DemoApplication"));
  var payloads = sourceFiles
      .Select(s => String.Format("<Payload SourceFile='{0}' Name='{1}' />", s, s.Replace(@"..\DemoApplication\publish\", "")));
  #>
  <Fragment>
    <PackageGroup Id="DemoApplicationBootstrapper">
      <ExePackage InstallCommand="Setup.exe" SourceFile="<#=sourceFiles.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.Contains("setup.exe"))#>">
<# foreach (var payload in payloads) { #>
        <#=payload#>
<# } #>
      </ExePackage>
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

It generates a WiX Fragment in .wxs file. Use a PackageGroupRef instead of a ExePackage in your Bundle.wsx.

*VS Tip: To add an existing file to a project without copying it, click the drop down arrow next to the Add button and choose "Add as link".*

*Build Tip: Normally, text transforms are only executed when the template is saved. This doesn't work well when the output depends on other files. To transform on every build use  [TransformOnBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee847423%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).*

### Alternative

On the other hand, you might prefer to not use the Microsoft Bootstrapper. You would then have to recreate each referenced packages as one or more Wix Bootstrapper ExePackage or MsiPacakges elements. For example, if you have a dependency on SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0, you can look into `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0\EN\package.xml`, see the installation file and command that are needed and code up an ExePackage element from that information.